# Setting up API with Laravel Passport - why am I getting an unauthorized error?

Tags: php, html, laravel, axios, laravel-passport

I am following along with a tutorial on building Laravel and Vue JS web apps, and I have a question:

I am trying to build an api using Laravel Passport, and I am getting the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
app.js:699 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

I just wondered why these errors might be occuring?
I have run the following commands:
'composer require laravel/passport'
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport install

User.php

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
```

config/auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

routes.php

```
    Route::post('/categories/upsert', 'CategoryController@upsert');
```

index.blade.php

```
    <template>
    <form>
        <a @click="addCategory" class="add">+ Add Category</a>
        <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="category.id">
            <input type="text" v-model="category.name"> {{/* inputs will use two way binding with v-model */}}
            <input type="number" v-model="category.display_order">
            <a @click="removeCategory(index)" class="remove">delete</a>
            <div>
                <img v-if="category.image" :src="` /images/${category.image}`" width="100">
                <label v-else>Image: </label>
                <input type="text" v-model.lazy="category.image">
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['initialCategories'],
            data() {
                return {
                    categories: _.cloneDeep(this.initialCategories) /* Cloned to avoid mutating the prop */
                };
            },
            created() {
                axios.post('/api/categories/upsert');
            },
            methods: {
                removeCategory(index) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure?')){
                        this.categories.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                },
                addCategory() {
                    this.categories.push({
                        id: 0,
                        name: '',
                        image: '',
                        display_order: this.categories.length + 1
                    });
                    this.nextTick(() => {
                        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                        this.$refs[''][0].focus();
                    });
                }
    
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. I have tried clearing the configuration cache and including a csrf token. Thanks,

Robert
London, UK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Passport suddenly returning 401 on Vue/Axios API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172790/laravel-passport-suddenly-returning-401-on-vue-axios-api-calls)

Comment: I have tried this out, and I have added this to my 'boot()' function in my AppServiceProvider:

    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::withoutCookieSerialization();
    }

But I am still getting the same 401 error :(

Answer (score 0):

You should run artisan command: `php artisan passport:install`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:
Add `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,` to you Kernel file under $middlewareGroups.

Add `Passport::routes();` to AuthServiceProvider, under boot function.

in routes/api.php, group your routes under

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {    

 //Routes here      

 });
```

Comment: root or boot function?

Comment: fixed the typo.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Saleh, all of these are present, and I have run npm run:watch and php artisan config:cache, but I'm still getting the same error - any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please make sure that you have changed the api driver to "passport" in config/auth.php

Comment: Also, check middlewaregroups in kernel.php, add 'auth:api', under 'api'